# Pass Query String Into Register Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm going to have a subscription flow as follows:

- User goes to pricing page, chooses plan, is redirected to ../Register?planId=1
- User registers with username and password, is forwarded to billing page, which needs to be ../Subscription/Billing?planId=1
- I added an integer, planId, to my RegisterViewModel

On pricing page, I have the links working correctly.

For register controller, I have:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model, int planId)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        return RedirectToAction("Pricing", "Home");
    }
    RegisterViewModel model1 = new RegisterViewModel();

    model1.planId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["planId"]);
    return View(model1);

}
```

And in Register view I have:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.planId)
```

However, this value is blank everytime I've run the application. If I can get the planId to be included as part of the register form submission, then I think I can redirect the controller to "../Subscription/Billing?planId=1" after registration.

Here's the current register post controller, where I think I just need to add the planid to the redirectToAction:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Role = "Admin", ReportsTo = "", ActiveUntil = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Pricing", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

My question is, how do I get the planid to pass from the query string to a hidden field in the login form?

Comment: so, What question you want to ask?

Comment: @NguyễnMinhĐức Added above. My question is how do I get the query string to pass into the register form as a hidden field?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["planId"]);` does not work?

Comment: @DucNguyen I'm not sure what isn't working. I only know that the value isn't being passed to the hidden field.

Comment: You can try `model1.planId = planId`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Submit as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept. @DucNguyen

Comment: done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `model1.planId = planId`